# Change TFS Local path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Can someone help me to change my tfs local path in eclipse? I have checked out to a folder earlier, now I have to change it to another location.

Answer (score 3):

Right click your project and choose **Team -- Manage Workspaces**, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Then select the workspace you are using and change the Local Folder path, check the screenshot below:

[image]